# // turns into / when parsing URL for image

Tags: android

I'm trying to convert a String which contains a URL into a URI object. However when I do

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
img.setImageURI(Uri.parse("http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg"));
```

but for some reason I'm getting an error saying

```
E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:/www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: I don't think setImageUri is used for downloading images. Rather loading images from file.

Comment: Ohhh, that would make sense considering I haven't seen anyone using it anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Use Picasso or Android Universal Image Loader for loading images from url.

Comment: @DamianKozlak Will Android Universal Image Loader do all the caching for me?

Comment: Yes. I have added link to useful tips as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for loading images from url.

Picasso has very nice API, but Android Universal Image Loader is very customizable. [Here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info) is useful info about caching.